# How to invoke a postgres function using arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

I have a Postgres function called 'move_to_end' that I'm invoking using find_by_sql as below:

```
def move_to_end
  self.class.find_by_sql ["select move_to_end(?)", id]
end
```

I'd like to replace the find_by_sql statement with an arel call, but all the examples I've found require arel to work with a table.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think something like `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('select move_to_end...')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using [NamedFunctions](https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/nodes/named_function.rb) in Arel.
However, you still have to use arel_table to reference table column in the query. One possible workaround is to alias it with underscore:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: solution
#
#  solution_id    :integer          not null, primary key
#  body    :text
#
class Solution
  class << self
    alias_method :_, :arel_table

    def only_checked
        _.project(checked(_[:solution_id]))
    end

    def checked
        Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('CHECKED', [query])
    end
  end
end 

Solution.only_checked.to_sql # -> SELECT CHECKED("solution"."solution_id") FROM "solution";
```

Comment: That works...had to rearrange the postgres function a bit. Thanks!